# What does getting the this pointer NULL in almost all the frames of a call stack from a dump suggest?

Tags: c++, this, heap-corruption

I have a situation where in one of our customers is seeing crashes with the product(Windows). I have the dumps from them and I have analyzed those cores. The crash seems to have occurred after a string is returned from a function. The function looks perfectly okay to me, although there is scope for fine tuning the same. I used Windbg to analyze the core. One thing that I found is that in every frame of the faulty threads' call stack the this pointer was NULL, except for the first frame where the value was good. So, I would like to know if this is a case of heap corruption or is there any other possibility?

Comment: Are you returning a local variable by reference?

Comment: You may be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer: while you call non-virtual functions that do not rely on the state of the object, you keep going; once you hit a virtual or try to look at a member variable, you hit an exception. Did you try using valgrind on your code?

Comment: In fact yes I agree that when we try to look into a member variable we are getting the crash. But, if I go back to the previous frames I find the this pointer as NULL. So, I was wondering, how or why the this is set to NULL!! I am trying to check the calling conventions. Well the product is on both Windows and AIX and the problem seems to be there only on the Windows version. So, we haven't used valgrind as such..

Answer (score 1):

What it probably shows is that debugging an optimised release mode build doesn't quite work. I'm not familiar with the details, but at least one of the optimisation modes ("/Oy - Frame Pointer Omission") affects the view of the stack when debugging.